# What is the maximum number of OR clauses within a single Oracle statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have to check against 100,000 uids for a single update statement - my code currently will break this into 1000-uid chunks:

```
[...] WHERE UID IN (..., '998', '999', '1000') 
OR UID IN ('1001', '1002', ...) 
OR (..., etc., ...)
```

Is there a maximum number of OR clauses you can have? I.e., in my example above, it would generate 100 OR clauses of 1000 IN clauses each.

Comment: I would put the uids in another table and join it in the update statement.

Comment: Where do those 100,000 uids come from?  Surely, those values are stored somewhere in the database, right?  If so, you can use the query that returns the UID values in your IN statement rather than explicitly listing out 100,000 separate literal values.

Comment: The 100,000 uids are populated into a deque at a different part of the process - not really possible to do that on the fly in this scenario.

Comment: @ctote, I'm ready to bet there are.

Comment: +1 for intermediate table join. You can use temporary table to store your deque and join against it. Don't forget about bulk inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**22.**

Well, not exactly.  That's how many OR clauses of 1000-item IN lists will run on *my* system, but that number will probably be different for everyone.  There is
no [database limit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn0043.htm) that exactly covers this scenario.  It probably falls under the Note:

> The limit on how long a SQL statement can be depends on many factors,
>   including database configuration, disk space, and memory

When I try 23, I get this error in SQL*Plus:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 2452
Session ID: 135 Serial number: 165
```

Which is not the real error, that just means the server crashed and SQL*Plus lost its connection.  Oddly, when I look in the alert log there are no errors.  There are trace files but still no ORA- error messages.  All I see is hundreds of lines like this:

```
*** 2013-11-04 21:59:48.667
minact-scn master-status: grec-scn:0x0000.00821c54 gmin-scn:0x0000.0081d656 gcalc-scn:0x0000.00821c54
minact-scn master-status: grec-scn:0x0000.00823b45 gmin-scn:0x0000.0081d656 gcalc-scn:0x0000.00823b46
```

The lesson here is to avoid ridiculously large SQL statements.  You'll have to do it another way, like loading the data into a table.  And don't try to build something that is *just* small enough.  It may work today but fail on a different environment tomorrow.

---

```
--Find the maximum number of IN conditions with 1000 items.
--Change the first number until it throws an error.
--This code uses dynamic SQL, but I found that static SQL has the same limit.
declare
    c_number_of_ors number := 22;

    v_in_sql varchar2(4000);
    v_sql clob;
    v_count number;
begin
    --Comma-separate list of 1000 numbers.
    select listagg(level, ',') within group (order by 1)
    into v_in_sql
    from dual connect by level <= 1000;

    --Start the statement.
    v_sql := 'select count(*) from dual ';
    v_sql := v_sql || 'where 1 in ('||v_in_sql||')';

    --Append more ORs to it.
    for i in 1 .. c_number_of_ors loop
        v_sql := v_sql || ' or '||to_char(i)||' in ('||v_in_sql||')';
    end loop;

    --Execute it.
    execute immediate v_sql into v_count;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no any limitation of OR clauses in a single query. You may have limitations issues when you are using GROUP BY clauses and in general terms all of the nondistinct aggregate functions (for example, SUM, AVG) that must fit within a single database block.